# Push uncommitted local git changes to a new remote fork

Tags: git, fork

I have a local git repo (call it local master) associated with a remote (master) repo. I have uncommitted changes in my local master. I want to:

1. push the local master changes to a new (remote) fork.
2. continue to work on the local master changes, and then push it to the remote master.

Can I do this without creating a local copy of the remote fork? If I must create a local copy of the remote fork, is there a way to git copy the changes from local master to local fork? (I mean avoid doing `cp localMaster/changedFiles localFork/changedFiles`).

Why am I doing this? I have ugly but working code locally. Before I clean it up, I thought I should stash it away in a remote fork, in case I needed to look at the different things I tried before I got it to working. I wasn't sure branching was a good idea for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A local repo can have multiple remotes that it can push to. So just create a new remote repo, add that as a `remote` to your local repo, and push any branches that you care to. If you create the remote repo at GitHub, for example, they give you instructions, right there, for doing exactly that.

Note that you cannot push uncommitted changes. Uncommitted changes are not "things" in Git. Only commits are "things". Uncommitted changes are just you talking to yourself, as it were.

Comment: [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) it worked, and exactly what I was looking for. Yes, I realize uncommitted changes are purely local - the new thing I learnt was having multiple remotes. Perfect!